# What is the correct name for those mathematical operations?

Tags: math, statistics

I am not an english speaker, however I need to write code where I need to include print messages in English, hence using english terminology from Math, statistics etc.

This is the case:
I have two lists and I compare them, let's say:
list 1 -  **1 2 3 4 5**
list 2 - **2 4 6**

So naturally when I compare both lists you see that  **2 4** are present in both lists. What is the operation itself called? Because when I try to translate it from my language to english it's "section" or "cutting". I don't believe that this is the official mathematical term for this operation.

Also I want to know what is it called when you show the things that are missing in both lists. For example **1 3 5 6** ?

Thanks and sorry for the silly question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intersection for {1,2,3,4,5} ; {2,4,6} = {2,4}
Symmetric difference for {1,2,3,4,5} ; {2,4,6} = {1,3,5,6}
```